# How to sum up grouped results in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to avoid involving php after this query. I have a table that holds a list of employees and how much time they worked in seconds,date, etc... i want to:

```
select SUM(`seconds`) between date A and date B group by WEEK(`date`)
```

that will give me results for each week but now i want to get an average seconds worked per week by using AVG() on the whole result set. How could you accomplish this in one query?

Comment: what about: `sum(seconds)/sum(employees)`

Comment: Why would i divide employees by seconds?

Comment: Could you provide a small example of data and expected results?

Comment: I have daily data, and i need to turn it into weekly data with averages and standard deviation and what not.

Comment: @MarshallHouse not "employees by seconds" but "seconds by employees" - to get the average number of seconds and employee worked on a specific week.

Comment: i'm trying to get "average hours per week" in a specified range of dates, could be a year.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are looking for with the average... 3 or 4 records of sample data and the expected results of the query would go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
Select AVG(sum_seconds) from (select SUM('seconds') as sum_seconds between date A and date B group by WEEK('date')) as a
```

Comment: did it work? Let me know as I don't have the data / haven't tested this. just wrote it out so there could be a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not going to use that code, but i like the concept. I was hoping there was a method to do it though.

Comment: i think not the average over sum of seconds per week, he is looking for average seconds per week. @Marshall, Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
select sum(total) from (select SUM(`seconds`) as total between date A and date B group by WEEK(`date`)) as tbl1
```

Hope it help